# Make Human to Blender with IK doesn't work as expected

Tags: rigging, makehuman, inverse-kinematics

I'm exporting the character from MakeHuman with the MHX format with a rig "CMU mb" or the "Game Engine". Then I imported the file to blender overriding the exported data and selecting the MHX as the Rig Type

[image: Rig Type]

After that I go to the MHX2 Runtime panel and switch all the FK to IK.

[image: MHX2 Runtime]

**My problem: it doesn't work, if I grab the hand (or any part) it doesn't work as expected.**

[image: grabbing]

My blender version is 2.78.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13620/makehuman-pose-broken-between-2-69-and-2-7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Autorun python scripts in user preferences